Запретить / Разрешить в боте на aiogram3 вводить текстовые сообщения
Пишу телеграмм бот на aiogram. Необходимо запретить ввод сообщений и взаимодействовать с ботом только кнопками. И только в одном меню, при нажатии конкретной кнопки, запрашивается текстовый ввод для поиска в базе. Если не запретить сообщения, то поиск происходит в базе всегда, как только пользователь отправляет любой текст, слово, букву.
Как вариант просить пользователя в начале сообщения писать слово, по которому можно будет начинать поиск в базе, все остальные сообщения игнорировать. Но не хочется усложнять процесс ввода запроса, чтоб пользователь не делал лишних ошибок.

а для чего у вас реализован поиск в базе на любое текстовое сообщение? поменяйте логику у бота, чтобы поиск в базе происходил только тогда, когда это действительно необходимо

Я только начинаю осваивать ботов. Понимаю, что любую текстовое сообщение, команду обрабатывает декоратор message_handler. Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку KeyboardButton 'Поиск', всплывает сообщение "введите параметр", пользователь вводит, и его перехватывает message_handler. Хотя бы в двух словах, как настроить конкретный хендлер на обработку введенных параметров для поиска. Благодарю.

было бы не плохо, если бы вы приложили свой код, чтобы можно было дать конкретный ответ или совет. Предварительно удалите из него Token. Дополните свой вопрос, нажав кнопку Править

@Znahar Вы никак не сможете пользователям запретить отправлять сообщения боту. Только настроить бота реагировать по разному на присылаемое пользователем. Используйте fsm. К примеру: Пользователь жмет кнопку Поиск, устанавливается state, бот ждет от пользователя искомую фразу, и только тогда начинает поиск. И, раз вы только начинаете изучать ботов, делайте это сразу с aiogram 3, а не со второй версии, которая не поддерживается уже

Благодарю за подсказку
